# Windows Batch file to sort subfolders

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have a folder, C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Photos2019, with over 100 subfolders. In each of those subfolders are photos, all with varying names, except 3 photos in each are the same. I'd like to be able to create a 2 subfolders in each of the folders in the directory, one called 'Base' and one called 'Other', and have the 3 files the same in all moved into the 'Base' folder, and everything else moved into the 'Other' folder, something like below.

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Photos2019
-Folder1/Base/Landscape.png
-Folder1/Base/Portrait.png
-Folder1/Base/Wide.png
-Folder1/Other/*.png

-Folder2/Base/Landscape.png
-Folder2/Base/Portrait.png
-Folder2/Base/Wide.png
-Folder2/Other/*.png
```

EDIT:
So far I've been able to make a batch script that I can run in each folder, and it will do the job. It's when I try and add in /r for looping it, that it keeps running but doesn't do the job at all.

I have;

```
for %%a in (.) do md "Base"
for %%a in (.) do md "Other"
for %%a in (.) do move "Portrait.png" "Base"
for %%a in (.) do move "Landscape.png" "Base"
for %%a in (.) do move "Wide.png" "Base"
for %%a in (.) do move "*.png" "Other"
```

This is what I want I'm trying to run in each subfolder.

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? [SU] isn't a scipt writing service. Lookup the commands `cd`,`md`,`for`,`move` in an open cmd window with an appended `/?` or online at http://ss64.com/nt

Comment: @lotpings I've edited the question to include what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I attest that the help of the `for` command needs several iterations of reading to be fully understood.

With an initial tree on my test RamDrive A:\

```
> tree /f a:\
A:\
└───Test
    ├───Folder1
    │       Landscape.png
    │       other.png
    │       Portrait.png
    │       Wide.png
    │
    └───Folder2
            Landscape.png
            other.png
            Portrait.png
            Wide.png
```

This batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\22\SU_1473860.cmd
@Echo off
set "StartDir=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Photos2019"
Rem set "StartDir=A:\Test"

set "Base=Landscape.png Portrait.png Wide.png"

CD /D "%StartDir%"

for /d %%D in (*) Do (
    MD "%%~fD\Base"
    MD "%%~fD\Other"
    for %%B in (%Base%) Do Move "%%~fD\%%B" "%%~fD\Base\" >Nul 2>&1
    Move "%%~fD\*.png" "%%~fD\Other" >Nul 2>&1
)
```

yields this result:

```
> tree /F a:\
A:\
└───Test
    ├───Folder1
    │   ├───Base
    │   │       Landscape.png
    │   │       Portrait.png
    │   │       Wide.png
    │   │
    │   └───Other
    │           other.png
    │
    └───Folder2
        ├───Base
        │       Landscape.png
        │       Portrait.png
        │       Wide.png
        │
        └───Other
                other.png
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you.